# Specifying execution platform in protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm trying to specify in protractor which platform specific tests should be executed on. In the base selenium implementation you do it like this (depending on the language binding you are using):

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "MAC");
```

I don't see how to do that in protractor itself. Is there a way to set this parameter in Protractor test code? I haven't seen anything about this in the references or in any google searches I have been doing on the problem.

**Edit:**
According to the answer of Andersson I have currently updated my conf.js file to the following, which now seems to be working:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',  
  'capabilities': {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    platform: 'WINDOWS'
  },
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify platform info in `conf.js` as:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',  
  'capabilities': {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    platform: 'MAC'
  },
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

Let me know if it's not exactly what you want

Comment: I tried that right now. My basic conf.js has browser, platform, seleniumAddress and specs as attributes/parameters, and I get the error "[13:09:06] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?", any idea what that issue might be?

Comment: Can you share exact `conf.js` you use? Update your ticket with this data

Comment: Yes the error persists, I get the same error as before.

Comment: Replace `browser` with `browserName`

Comment: That worked, thank you. I updated the original post with the fixed conf.js